# How to keep the scheduled job in the list when tomcat is restarted

Tags: java

I'm using `Quartz simple Trigger`,the problem is that when the server is stopped and restarted the job is no longer in the scheduler.

How do I keep the scheduled job in the list?

Answer (score 0):

When you are scheduling, set the schedule the job's StorageType as `StorageType.PERSISTED`.

This will help you resume your job even if the server is restarted.

Comment: can u please explain me clearly.I used setRequestsRecovery method but it is not working.